# How does dependency injection aid object composition?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection

So say I have class A, B, and C. Class A has a single responsibility but needs functionality from class B and C so at first I wanted to get A to inherit from B and C then realized by following the "composition over inheritance" principle and making B and C members of A I could reduce the rigidity of the design and make those two classes more reusable.

At first B and C only needed to be instantiated in the constructor of A but eventually they had methods that needed to be called in two or three other places- as I was reusing the classes elsewhere I was forgetting to call some of the methods in the right places creating a lot of unnecessary defects and time wasted... my question is does dependency injection help with this problem, does it help reduce the complexity of using composition, and if so how?

```
public class A
{
     private mB;
     private mC;
     public A(IB b, IC c)
     {
         mB = b;
         mC = c;
     }
     public MethodX()
     {
         mB.DoWhatever();
     }
     public MethodY()
     {
         mC.DoSomething();
     }
}
```

From what I understand DI would let me configure what concrete classes for IB and IC get put through the constructor like this and handle its creation- but how else would it help (complexity wise)?

I decided to ask this question based on not understanding this article: http://lostechies.com/chadmyers/2010/02/13/composition-versus-inheritance/

For a real life example, say I have a State class that contains an EventListener class which has to register its events when the State calls its Begin method, unregister when it calls its End method.

Comment: This question might be better suited in the code review. http://codereview.stackexchange.com. It sounds like you need to use an interface as well and an abstract base class with virtual methods so you can override them and provide default implementations.

Comment: [codereview.se] or [programmers.se], either one. Not here, in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is sound, and you are on the right track.

The use of DI and composition via interfaces/abstractions makes it bot easier to tst and construct the code. You can use temporary "fake" implementations of B and C while building A, if that helps your process.

The typical solution is to factor the construction and configuration of A, B and C out into a factory class or a subclass of A.

Comment: So, in the factory would I do something like analyse the constructor of my State and discover that it depends on an IEventListener then look at my configuration which tells me to create an EventListener for it and in addition the config says to wrap the State in a IStateEventListenerDecorator decorator that handles registration and unregistration of events over top of IState's own Begin and End methods?

Comment: Something like that. Or use a framework for creating the instances in the right order from a configuration file. That's another popular option. Plus: You can just edit the file, and it's machine writable. Minus: You basically have to learn another programming languare on top of the one you're already using. The point is to separate the way the code works and objects interact from what concrete implementations are used, and how they are created.

Answer (score 3):

Dependency Injection doesn't aid object composition at all.  You need a degree of composability before you can even use injection.  Generally Dependency Inversion is used to invert conventional dependencies so that dependencies can be modelled by abstractions which themselves can be injected into something else without a direct coupling.  Injection is a form of inversion that aids in decoupling, not composition.

Answer (score 0):

I think your understanding of DI is correct. 
By removing instantiation of classes B and C from class A, DI makes them less coupled with each other. Now class A depends on the abstract interfaces IB and IC, and not on their concrete implementations. This makes code of class A more flexible (you can easily inject some other implementations of IB and IC if needed by simply reconfiguring your DI container), and testable (you can inject mock implementations of IB and IC). 
Also, it arguably makes code of class A more readable, because now its dependency on collaborators IB and IC is explicitly manifested by the signature of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection offsets complexity to a degree when dealing with dependencies by automating and governing the creation of those dependencies. (When implemented with an IOC Container such as Autofac or Unity) In a simple example of A, B, and C it's probably pretty difficult to see any real savings. Where you start to see lowering of complexity is when you implement class D with a dependency on C. An IOC Container facilitating your DI will know how to compose an A, B, and C (using an A & B) so your hand-rolled code doesn't need to worry about creating instances of objects to pass as dependencies. By complexity I'm referring to the amount of code/babysitting needed to govern dependencies.

Where IOC and DI really shine are as Peter points out, in de-coupling dependencies from one another so that code can be tested in isolation. If you want to write unit tests for class C, but C creates instances of A & B, it cannot be tested in isolation from A & B. When A or B is something like a data service, or file service this can make unit testing painful. Utilizing IOC, C accepts references to contract interfaces for those services which can be mocked out. This way C can be tested with predictable behaviour from its dependencies.